# Servlets: How to add an user to a role programatically

Tags: java, servlets

I defined security roles in web.xml (Refer: this [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2015/09/setting-role-based-security-in-tomcat.html)). I would like to expose an API, where admin can create new users and assign roles to them.

How can I achieve roles adding to users programatically?

Comment: Welcome; Please share some source code you're trying. :)

Comment: I am thinking to override 'public boolean isUserInRole(String role)' method in my wrapper class. But I want to know, is there any way in servlets that I can add this user to that role (instead of configuring in tomcat-users.xml file)

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761721/how-to-programatically-add-users-to-tomcat-userdatabaserealm) adds users but the ideas are similar for roles.